# Can anyone help me out with this?

Tags: pattern, visual

Can someone help me out with this? I tried a-lot of combinations to see which one it would logically be, but I'm stuck as of this moment.

[image: Puzzle]

Comment: What is the source of this puzzle?

Comment: Seems like a rotation puzzle

Comment: The answer is clearly a or b, but possibly c with a change for d too. Case closed.

Answer (score 35):

It's:

> C. The last box in a row contains the elements that the previous two boxes have in common.

Comment: Well, that's clearly the answer.

Answer (score -3):

The answer is C. The puzzle would make more sense if the puzzle had consistent factors both vertically and horizontally (instead of just horizontally). Edit2: Nope. It's not all one puzzle. It's two examples followed by a puzzle. Whoever made this doesn't understand the benefits of spacing.

Edit1:
Oh, I'm being downvoted! Thanks for the warm Stack-exchange welcome!

Anyway, boboquack wants me to update my answer. so here you go: It appears that there are at least two potentially consistent factors per horizontal row. This rules out B and D. None of the factors that have been removed from previous panels in the first two rows were added back in later panels on the same row. Therefore A doesn't seem logically consistent with the rest of the puzzle. With so little information that's more of an assumption than a provable trend, but it's enough information to make C a more likely answer, as there's no potential reason for it not to be.

Though, in hindsight, it appears that my method for solving this puzzle is a bit more... roundabout than Johnmark Perry's. (I clearly made this puzzle into something more complicated than it is after overlooking something simple; I initially mistook this for a grid puzzle rather than three different examples, and approached it as such. Some spacing would make the puzzle more clear, honestly)

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?

Comment: Each section of the puzzle has a consistent horizontal factor: the bottom left dot in the first row, the square in the second row, and the top left dot in the last row. The puzzle would be more clear if there were also vertically consistent factors.

Comment: So why not A? By the way, explaining your answer should be done in your actual answer.

Comment: Alright, I updated it. It's nice getting downvoted just because I tried to participate, btw. Makes me feel right at home. (I'm not accusing you, but still)

Comment: Edited a few more times. The puzzle is poorly designed. examples should be more clearly separated from the actual puzzle.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)**)  Sorry your welcome has been a bit rocky - I think it's mostly because you've added an answer to a question that already had a correct answer, and due to your own admitted misunderstanding of the puzzle your answer wasn't as concise or complete as the prior one. You should always look at existing answers before providing one of your own, to ensure you are not just adding a duplicate. Hopefully your next attempt will fare better!